# Weird animation behavior using Swift 4 and UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiview

I really can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Let me explain in detail what was my aim:

- I have two `UIView` in the same `UIViewController`. They're called "`redSquare`" and "`greenSquare`".
- When the `UIViewController` is presented I want to animate the `redSquare` in order to move on the Y-axis till it reaches the top-border of the `greenSquare`.

This is how I set the xCode project:

[image]

The behavior that I got is completely the opposite and I really can't understand why and what's happening:

[image]

Any tips or explanations for this?

Comment: Can you provide details as to whether obj2 and obj1 are both subviews of the same view?

Comment: Which one is `obj1` and which one is `obj2`?

Comment: Question updated, sorry if it was confusing at the beginning

Comment: are you using AutoLayout?  How do you get the red square initially positioned over the green square?

Comment: @michaelDautermann Yes I do. I created constraints with autolayout. `redSquare` = Align center to X,Y and height set to 80. `greenSquare` = Align center to X, Trailing and Leading space set to 35 and Height equals to 180.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay.  Part of the problem is that you're aligning the center Y... which means that you're trying to break constraints with your animation.

Another part of the problem is that you are doing your animation in `viewDidLoad`, which totally runs before `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` get called.

For my own animations, I usually animate a *constraint*.

That is, get rid of the center-Y constraint for your red box and add a new constraint putting the red box some Y distance from the bottom of the superview.  Connect this new constraint to an outlet and then you can animate like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var redYConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // This line sets the red box to be in the center Y of the green box
    self.redYConstraint.constant = self.greenSquare.frame.midY
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 2.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.redYConstraint.constant = self.greenSquare.frame.maxY
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you made my day! This is the very first time that I use storyboards and constraints (I used to programming in SpriteKit).